# FirePHP Suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, firebug, firephp

My FirePHP modules seems to have stopped working. Instead I get this error message:

```
["There was a problem wri...ePHP/FirebugConsole/0.1",
TypeError: node is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/lib/domplate.js

domplate.js (line 515)
<System>
]
```

I suspect it is related to using FirePHP for Chrome, but I have removed that with no joy!

Comment: Have you tried a Google Chrome port? https://github.com/andrewn/firephp-chrome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ali, you're right, thanks for resolving this issue!

[FirePHP Extension for Firefox 8+ & Firebug 1.9+](https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.sourcemint.com/github.com/firephp/firephp-extension/-stream/stable/firephp-extension-0.7.0rc2.xpi)

Answer (score 21):

It's because Firefox has been updated to 9

Go to FirePHP page and update to 0.7.0rc2

Comment: Actually, it is because of Firebug updating to 1.9. The FirePHP Extension 0.7.x adds support for Firebug 1.9.